# Simple user login with JSTL

Tags: xml, jsp, servlets

I have tried to create some java Servlet files based on the tutorial I found online. And now, I want to create a simple login but I keep getting HTTP:// 404.

LoginServlet.java

```
package example;

@WebServlet(name = "logina", urlPatterns = { "/logina" })
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throwsServletException, IOException {

    String a = request.getParameter("username");
    String result;
    if("a".equals(a)) {
        result = "good";
    } else {
        result = "bad";
    }
    request.setAttribute("result", result);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
}
```

login.jsp

```
<form action="/example/logina" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<%String rq = request.getParameter("result");
out.println(rq);
%>
```

1. Since I am using notation @WebSevlet, do I need to create servlet mapping in web.xml? I heard that since we are using Servlet 3.0, we no longer need web.xml file (I also tried to user the web.xml but it doesnt work neither).
2. Since my login.java in under example package, should I include /example/logina in the form action or /logina is fine as long as it matches with the servlet urlPatterns?
3. How the servlet urlPatterns look like if my login.jsp is under users folder? will it be /users/logina?

Answer (score 0):

> Since I am using notation @WebSevlet, do I need to create servlet mapping in web.xml? I heard that since we are using Servlet 3.0, we no longer need web.xml file (I also tried to user the web.xml but it doesnt work neither).

No , you need not it is the purpose of annotations

> Since my login.java in under example package, should I include
>   /example/logina in the form action or /logina is fine as long as it
>   matches with the servlet urlPatterns?

`url` inside the action must match your servlet's `urlPatterns`

> How the servlet urlPatterns look like if my login.jsp is under users
>   folder? will it be /users/logina

To understand this , you should have it like this  `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("users/login.jsp");`

Comment: Thank for the reply. So as long as the url inside the action matches with the servlet's urlPatterns and they both are distinct form another url. I have tried that in my code, but it doesnt work. My login.jsp is not inside the users folder. I just wanna give a case that I may to change the urlPatterns to match with path of url inside the action, but seem like I dont need to worry about that.

Comment: have you tried replacing as `action="/logina"` in your form ?

Comment: Yes, I did. That was my first attempt of the implementation. But since it does not work also.